# Properly escaping quotations within a string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this regex which is supposedly the be-all-end-all for detecting HTML tags. I found it here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2004/10/25/usingregularexpressionstomatchhtml.aspx/

The original regex is below:

```
</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>
```

When I add single quotes around it, it becomes:

```
'</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>'
```

but this leaves the inner part `('.\*?')` as a different entity from the string I want to make. Any ideas how to fix this? Escaping those inner quotes around .*? doesn't seem to help since I get an EOL while scanning string error

Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend using a parser such as BeautifulSoup to handle this task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes to quote the entire regex.

```
>>> obj = re.compile(r"</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>")
>>> obj.pattern
'</?\\w+((\\s+\\w+(\\s*=\\s*(?:\\".*?\\"|\'.*?\'|[^\'\\">\\s]+))?)+\\s*|\\s*)/?>'
```

**Note** I have escaped the double quotes within the regex as `\"`